# Direct sum of group rings

Tags: ring-theory

Let $R=R_1 \bigoplus R_2$ be the external direct sum of two rings $R_1$ and $R_2$ and let $G$ be an arbitrary group. Is the group ring $RG \cong R_1G \bigoplus R_2G $? Using this, can we extend it for $R=R_1 \bigoplus R_2 \bigoplus R_3$ ?

I have used the natural map and proved it is well defined. How to show it is a homomorphism and further it is one-one and onto?

Comment: Does your book demand that ring homomorphisms send $1$ to $1$? Or is it enough that $h(xy) = h(x)h(y)$?

Comment: Do you assume that rings have a multiplicative identity and that homomorphisms preserve the identity? In that case, the infinite direct sum $R = \bigoplus_i R_i$ is not a ring. And $R_1 \times R_2$ only satisfies the universal property of the direct product, so it's bad form to call it the direct sum.

Answer (score 0):

**Caution** I am assuming in this answer that the OP's definition of "ring" does not include a demand that there is a unit element $1$, and as such, that homomorphisms don't need to respect such an element. In that case $\oplus$ really does fulfill the universal property we would want form a coproduct / direct sum, and the infinite direct sum construction is actually a ring.

The natural map
$$
f:(R_1\oplus R_2)G \to R_1G \oplus R_2G
$$
would be given by $f((r_1, r_2)g) = (r_1g, r_2g)$, and extended to general elements by linearity. Surjectivity is rather straight-forward to prove: Take a basis element in $R_1G\oplus R_2G$, and rewrite it:
$$
(ag,bg') = (ag,0g) + (0g',bg'),\quad a \in R_1\quad b\in R_2\quad g,g' \in G
$$
and we see that this is $f((a, 0)g + (0,b)g')$. For a general element
$$
\sum_{i = 1}^n(a_ig_i, b_ig_i')
$$
we do the same to each term. This concludes surjectivity.

For injectivity, say we have an element $x \in RG$ that is sent to $0$. That element is of the form $x = \sum_{i = 1}^n(a_i,b_i)g_i$. Let's assume that all the $g_n$ are distinct (if they are not already, then it may be made so by the distributive law). When we use $f$ on $x$, we get
$$
f(x) = \sum_{i = 1}^n(a_ig_i, b_ig_i) = (0,0)
$$
Now, especially, this means that the sum in each component is $0$, so we have
$$
a_1g_1+\ldots +  a_ng_n = 0, \quad b_1g_1 + \cdots +b_ng_n = 0
$$
The crux here is to note that while $R_1G$ is a ring, it is also a free $R_1$-module, with $\{g \in G\}$ as basis. Since all $g_i$ are assumed distinct, we must have that $a_i = 0$ for every $i$. A similar argument give $b_i = 0$ for all $i$. Therefore we conclude that $x = 0$, which means $f$ is injective.

As for the infinite case, yes, it is also true. The important thing to remember is that we are talking about direct *sums*, which means that any element in $\bigoplus_{i = 1}^\infty R_i$ can be split into a *finite* sum of elements of the form $(0,0,\ldots,0,r,0,\ldots)$, whith only one non-zero term. Then you can use the same argument as I did above to show surjectivity.

For injectivity, the argument doesn't really change, you just have infinitely many other equations saying $c_1g_1 + \cdots + c_ng_n = 0$ and the same for $d_i, e_i$, and so on. You still show in one fell swoop that they all have to be $0$.